# More efficient strategy for Optional Parameter tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am passing lists into my stored procedure so the user can choose their product lines, manufacturers, and categories for the search they're doing.  They don't have to provide this criteria and if they do not then the search occurs across all of those lines, manufacturers, and/or categories.  I have two strategies and I'm trying to decide which is more efficient.

Strategy #1 is Dyanmic SQL which I try to avoid but after reading Sommarskog articles I'm considering using.  Examples...

```
IF @productLines IS NOT NULL 

BEGIN
     CREATE TABLE #TempProductLines (lineID uniqueidentifier)

     INSERT INTO @TempProductLines
     SELECT gID FROM dbo.f_ConvertGuidList_To_Table(@productLines) --varchar list of Guid values
END   

SET @sql = "SELECT * FROM tblRL_PRoducts p "
IF @proudctLInes IS NOT NULL
SET @sql = @sql + " JOIN tblRL_PRoductLines pl ON p.prodID=pl.prodID "

SET @sql = @sql + " WHERE....."   --- where clause

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramlist,... params
```

Strategy #2, avoid Dynamic SQL using LEFT JOINs

```
CREATE TABLE #TempProductLines (lineID uniqueidentifier)

INSERT INTO @TempProductLines
SELECT gID FROM dbo.f_ConvertGuidList_To_Table(@productLines) --varchar list of Guid values

SELECT * 
FROM tblRL_PRoducts p
 LEFT JOIN #TempProductLines pl ON p.prodID=pl.prodID

WHERE 
   (
     (
       @productLInes IS NOT NULL
       AND
       pl.lineID IS NOT NULL
     )
     OR
     @productLines IS NULL
   )
   AND
   (
     .... rest of WHERE clause
   )
```

I would end up actually having 7 blocks above for different potential lists used in searching.

Answer (score 0):

I use the "MYCOUNT = 0 or exists" trick.

You can see it fully here:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stored+Procedures/thezerotonparameterproblem/2283/

Wow.  I need to update that for non OPENXML and to use exists instead of "IN" clauses.

Below is the more modern version of that code.  Just run it against an existing Northwind database.

```
/*  START TSQL CODE */

/*  Stored Procedure Definition */

Use Northwind
GO


IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = N'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' and ROUTINE_NAME = N'uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams'  
    )
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams]
END


GO

CREATE Procedure dbo.uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams(
@parametersXML XML
)
AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON


    /* build a table (variable) to store the xml-based result set (for specific orderid's) */
    DECLARE @orderCount int
    DECLARE @orders TABLE ( /* used to track which specific OrderID's you want */
    OrderID int
    )

    DECLARE @customerCount int DECLARE @customers TABLE ( /* used to track which specific customers you want  */
    CustomerID varchar(5) 
    )

    declare @dateOrderDateAfter datetime /* used to track with orders with OrderDate after you want */
    declare @dateOrderDateBefore datetime /* used to track with orders with OrderDate before you want */

    /* build a table (table-variable) to store the xml-based result set (for specific Countries) */
    DECLARE @customerCountryCount int DECLARE @customerCountry TABLE ( /* used to track which specific Countries you want */
    CountryName varchar(15) )


    /* Start XML usage */  
    /* Only incur the penalty of XML parsing, if XML was specified */
    if (@parametersXML IS NOT NULL) AND (Datalength(@parametersXML) > 10 ) 
        /* Only process the xml If the xml exists, and it has at least 10 chars. 10 is just a somewhat */ 
        /* arbritrary number, saying, that an xml doc with <10 chars doesn't have a whole lot going for it */ /* || DataLength is used for Text datatype  */

    BEGIN


        /*  (Do not forget that XML (and xpaths below) are CASE SENSITIVE, no matter what your database collation happens to be.) */
        INSERT INTO @orders ( OrderID )
        SELECT T.parameter.value('(OrderID)[1]', 'INT') AS OrderID
        FROM @parametersXML.nodes('ParametersDS/Order') AS T(parameter);

        INSERT INTO @customers (CustomerID)
        SELECT T.parameter.value('(CustomerID)[1]', 'varchar(5)') AS CustomerID
        FROM @parametersXML.nodes('ParametersDS/Customer') AS T(parameter);

        /* Note, a single scalar value below */
        SELECT @dateOrderDateBefore = (
        SELECT T.parameter.value('(OrderDateBefore)[1]', 'datetime') AS OrderDateBefore
        FROM @parametersXML.nodes('ParametersDS/SingleValueParam') AS T(parameter) );

        /* Note, a single scalar value below */
        SELECT @dateOrderDateAfter =  (
        SELECT T.parameter.value('(OrderDateAfter)[1]', 'datetime') AS OrderDateAfter
        FROM @parametersXML.nodes('ParametersDS/SingleValueParam') AS T(parameter) );

        INSERT INTO @customerCountry (CountryName)
        SELECT T.parameter.value('(CountryName)[1]', 'varchar(15)') AS CountryName
        FROM @parametersXML.nodes('ParametersDS/CustomerCountry') AS T(parameter);

    END 
    /* End XML usage */


    /* These count variables help distinquish between when a parameter is and isn't specified */
    select @orderCount = count(*) from @orders 
    select @customerCount = count(*) from @customers 
    select @customerCountryCount = count(*) from @customerCountry 
    /* Note, if the xml doesn't supply any dates, @dateOrderDateBefore and @dateOrderDateAfter will remain null  */

    /* */
    /* Debugging queries */
    /*
    select * from @orders 
    select * from @customers 
    print @dateOrderDateBefore 
    print @dateOrderDateAfter 
    select * from @customerCountry 
    */

    /* Above are the variables and variable-tables for parameters */
    /**/

    DECLARE @ordersWhichMetCriteriaTable TABLE ( /* used to track the orderid's we're interested in */
    OrderID int ) 

    /* A new variable table holds (just) the OrderID's which meet the input parmeters. 
     You'll see the use of the @ordersWhichMetCriteriaTable later. 
     */

    Insert into @ordersWhichMetCriteriaTable 
    SELECT 
        OrderID 
    FROM 
        Orders o 
    /* Note, this below join to the Customers table is only necessary because of the Country */
    /* if you didn't want to retrieve the Customer.Country column, you could leave this join out */
    INNER JOIN Customers c 
        ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
    WHERE 
                /* the parentheses play an important role, so be careful altering them */
        /* */
        (
            (@orderCount = 0) 
            OR
            ( exists (select null from @orders innerVariableTable where innerVariableTable.OrderID = o.OrderID ))
        ) 

        /* */
        AND 
        (
            (@customerCount = 0) 
            OR
            ( exists (select null from @customers innerVariableTable where innerVariableTable.CustomerID = o.CustomerID ))
        ) 

        /* */
        AND (( @dateOrderDateBefore IS NULL ) OR (o.OrderDate <= @dateOrderDateBefore )) 

        /* */
        AND (( @dateOrderDateAfter IS NULL ) OR (o.OrderDate >= @dateOrderDateAfter )) 

        /* */
        AND 
            /*CountryName is a string, so watch the case sensitivity, get around this by using UPPER() function */
            (
                (@customerCountryCount = 0) 
                OR
                ( exists (select null from @customerCountry innerVariableTable where UPPER(innerVariableTable.CountryName) = UPPER(c.Country)  ))
            ) 
    /*  ORDER BY is unnecessary here */



    /* Below are 3 queries/result sets we're interested in. Notice the piggyback off the @ordersWhichMetCriteriaTable every time. */ 
    /* */
    /* */

    /* ResultSet #1 */
    /* All Customer Information (for the specific orders in the @ordersWhichMetCriteriaTable table) */
    SELECT 
        c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName,c.ContactName,c.ContactTitle,c.[Address],c.City,c.Region,c.PostalCode,c.Country ,c.Phone,c.Fax 
    FROM 
        Customers c 
        JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
    WHERE 
        exists (select null from @ordersWhichMetCriteriaTable innerHolder where innerHolder.OrderID = o.OrderID )
    ORDER BY 
        c.CustomerID 

    /* */
    /* ResultSet #2 */ 
    /*All Order Information (for the specific orders in the @ordersWhichMetCriteriaTable table) */
    SELECT o.OrderID,o.CustomerID,o.EmployeeID,o.OrderDate,o.RequiredDate,o.ShippedDate,o.ShipVia ,o.Freight,o.ShipName,o.ShipAddress,o.OrderID,o.CustomerID,o.EmployeeID,o.OrderDate 
    FROM 
        Orders o 
     WHERE 
        exists (select null from @ordersWhichMetCriteriaTable innerHolder where innerHolder.OrderID = o.OrderID )
    ORDER BY 
        o.CustomerID , o.OrderID 

    /* */
    /* ResultSet #3 */
    /* All Order Detail Information (for the specific orders in the @ordersWhichMetCriteriaTable table) */
     SELECT od.OrderID,od.ProductID,od.UnitPrice,od.Quantity,od.Discount 
     FROM 
        [Order Details] od 
     WHERE 
        exists (select null from @ordersWhichMetCriteriaTable innerHolder where innerHolder.OrderID = od.OrderID )
     ORDER BY 
        od.OrderID 


END

GO 


/* */
/*  The user stored procedure definition is above, the use of the user stored procedure is below.  */
/*  (Put the below code in a new Query Analyser window) */
/*  "How to Use" the procedure above. (Put this code in a new Query Analyser window.) */

/* */

Use Northwind
GO

/* no parameters */
print 'No Filters, Just Give me back all the Data'
EXEC uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams '
<ParametersDS>
</ParametersDS>
'

GO


/* just CustomerID */
print 'Filter on specific Customers'
EXEC uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams '
<ParametersDS>

 <Customer>
  <CustomerID>CENTC</CustomerID>
 </Customer>
 <Customer>
  <CustomerID>GROSR</CustomerID>
 </Customer>


</ParametersDS>
'


GO



/* Order Dates (Before) */
print 'Filter on the OrderDates being Before'
EXEC uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams '
<ParametersDS>
 <SingleValueParam>
  <OrderDateBefore>7/7/1996</OrderDateBefore>
 </SingleValueParam>
</ParametersDS>
'

GO

/* Order Dates (After) */
print 'Filter on the OrderDates being After'
EXEC uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams '
<ParametersDS>
 <SingleValueParam>
  <OrderDateAfter>5/5/1998</OrderDateAfter>
 </SingleValueParam>
</ParametersDS>
'

GO


/* Order Dates (both) */
print 'Filter on the OrderDates being (before and after) the input dates'
EXEC uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams '
<ParametersDS>
 <SingleValueParam>
  <OrderDateBefore>12/31/1997</OrderDateBefore>
  <OrderDateAfter>1/1/1997</OrderDateAfter>
 </SingleValueParam>
</ParametersDS>
'

GO





print 'Filter on specific OrderIDs'
EXEC uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams '
<ParametersDS>

 <Order>
  <OrderID>10265</OrderID>
 </Order>
 <Order>
  <OrderID>10267</OrderID>
 </Order>
 <Order>
  <OrderID>10269</OrderID>
 </Order>

</ParametersDS>
'


GO

/* Specific Countries */
print 'Filter on specific Countries'
EXEC uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams '
<ParametersDS>

 <CustomerCountry>
  <CountryName>Austria</CountryName>
 </CustomerCountry>

 <CustomerCountry>
  <CountryName>Belgium</CountryName>
 </CustomerCountry>


</ParametersDS>
'
GO



/* Specific Countries */
print 'Filter on specific Countries and OrderDate'
EXEC uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams '
<ParametersDS>

 <CustomerCountry>
  <CountryName>AustriA</CountryName>
 </CustomerCountry>

 <CustomerCountry>
  <CountryName>BelgiuM</CountryName>
 </CustomerCountry>

 <SingleValueParam>
  <OrderDateBefore>2/28/1997</OrderDateBefore>
  <OrderDateAfter>1/1/1997</OrderDateAfter>
 </SingleValueParam>

</ParametersDS>
'







print 'Order ID that does not exist'
EXEC uspOrderDetailsGetByXmlParams '
<ParametersDS>

 <Order>
  <OrderID>-9999</OrderID>
 </Order>


</ParametersDS>
'


GO

/*  END TSQL CODE  */
```